# Editable components

Tags: cms

I would like to include global editable components in a website I am currently making with the 1.4 Symfony framework. Are there any plugin/library/anything that could do that?

#### My attempts

- The best solution would have been something like http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineEditableComponentPlugin. However:

  - This plugin is still in alpha.
  - I could not have it work (though it may be because I made an error during installation)
  - The slots are not global.
- One idea would be to use a CMS. I tried with Apostrophe. However I did not succeed in inserting a_slots in templates of "normal" actions. It seems you can only inserts slots in pages created by Apostrophe. A solution could be to create a template for each pages/action. Then I could create an apostrophe page for each of those templates. But that would mean transferring all the Controller part in the templates, losing the assets of a MVC architecture.
- Doing it myself. I could do that, but I would have the feeling of reinventing the wheel. My needs do not seem quite specific, so I hope someone have done it before.

#### The context

I am currently making a website for an association of theater, dance and music. We produce an average of 1.5 spectacles by month plus some other events. In the current version of the website, I have done a backend application where you can edit all the informations about a given event. However, some people find it hard/weird to need to go to another page. Sometimes they mistake two fields; WYSIWYGs editable components seem perfect to me. They need to be global (indeed the title of an event appear in multiple pages).

Answer (score 1):

See '[including other templates](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html)':-

Quoting from the author...

> You'll often want to include the same template or code fragment on
>   several different pages. For example, in an application with "news
>   articles", the template code displaying an article might be used on
>   the article detail page, on a page displaying the most popular
>   articles, or in a list of the latest articles.
>
> When you need to reuse a chunk of PHP code, you typically move the
>   code to a new PHP class or function. The same is true for templates.
>   By moving the reused template code into its own template, it can be
>   included from any other template. First, create the template that
>   you'll need to reuse.
>
> **Content to reuse**

```
<!-- src/Acme/ArticleBundle/Resources/views/Article/articleDetails.html.php -->
<h2><?php echo $article->getTitle() ?></h2>
<h3 class="byline">by <?php echo $article->getAuthorName() ?></h3>

<p>
    <?php echo $article->getBody() ?>
</p>
```

> **Include example**

```
<!-- src/Acme/ArticleBundle/Resources/Article/list.html.php -->
<?php $view->extend('AcmeArticleBundle::layout.html.php') ?>

<?php $view['slots']->start('body') ?>
    <h1>Recent Articles</h1>

    <?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
        <?php echo $view->render('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:articleDetails.html.php', array('article' => $article)) ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $view['slots']->stop() ?>
```

Comment: Thanks but it answers only partially to my question : What I really want is editable content. The only plugin I found doing it is in alpha version, and I could not have it work. Unless I find a stable plugin with editable component, the question of whether the editable component are global is meaningless.

Comment: @matthieuP then I would question if Symfony is the right choice for your build - this is a fairly common feature of most frameworks and it sounds like it's too immature for your needs.